# Using FxCop code analysis for .NET 4.5 applications

Tags: fxcop

Is it possible to use [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) for .NET 4.5 applications?

I am looking to use FxCop with the [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013) Professional edition.

Comment: Yes. What problems are you having?

Comment: I read that FxCop 1.36 supports upto .Net 4.0 and am not sure if it supports that latest versions. Could you please provide any reference for using FxCop with VS 2013 (.Net 4.5)

Comment: 1.38? I don't know. Version 10.0 works fine for me here, but I have ReSharper and maybe that does some magic that VS can't figure out on its own? I ask again what problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2013 Professional comes with Static Code Analysis (which is FxCop, just a fancy name for it).

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx) link some information is provided:

> As a developer, you can run code analysis on your project automatically or you can run it manually.
>
> To run code analysis each time that you build a project, you select Enable Code Analysis on Build (defines CODE_ANALYSIS constant) on the project's Property Page. For more information, see How to: Enable and Disable Automatic Code Analysis for Managed Code.
>
> To run code analysis manually on a project, on the Analyze menu, click Run Code Analysis on ProjectName. For more information, see How to: Enable and Disable Automatic Code Analysis for Managed Code.

This version runs perfectly on .NET 4.5.

---

FxCop 1.36 is a standalone version of Code Analysis. Microsoft no longer supports or works on the standalone version and currently only working on the integrated version that is included in Visual Studio.

There is a Uservoice going on which asks Microsoft to update the standalone FxCop version. See [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3243367-update-standalone-fxcop-to-support-net-4-5-and-po) link.

Comment: While I'm sure it's technically true that FxCop 1.36 is no longer supported FxCop 10.0 (from Windows 7 SDK) is AFAIK.

Comment: As you can see in this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544 ... FxCop 10.0 does not support .NET4.5, which is what the question was about. Also, there is no plan to further develop the standalone version of FxCop, hence the uservoice opened to get the VS-team to release a new version supporting 4.5.

Comment: No, I can't see that. In either case, FxCop 10 works fine with .Net 4.5 in our (SonarQube) setup, despite Microsofts lack of support. But I concede that your millage may vary, and from what I remember setting it up was a big PITA.

Comment: The link provided actually shows the supported .NET framework versions, under system requirements. Where official support shows that 4.0 is the latest supported, there ofcourse may be a workaround to get this working for 4.5. But seeing as the questionstarter uses visual studio 2013; he is probably best off using the built in code analysis.

Comment: Alternatively the page may simply be out of date. Plenty of theories. Gendarme is probably better anyway. :)